# Keyboard navigation on radio buttons of jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a problem with selecting radiobuttons using the arrow keys on a tablet (with keyboard dock). For normal buttons the selection works, but not for radiobuttons.

```
<body>      
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div id="type_selection" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <input type="radio" id="radio_option1" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio_option1">Option 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio_option2" name="radio" /><label for="radio_option2">Option 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio_option3" name="radio" /><label for="radio_option3">Option 3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio_option4" name="radio" /><label for="radio_option4">Option 4</label>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Selecting a regular button with the keyboard is not a problem:

```
<button id="btn_dothat" data-inline="true">That</button>
```

Anyway to fix this or is this a limitation of jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Use `checkboxradio("refresh")` to update the radio buttons

### UPDATE:

Rather than using `div` for `control group`, use `fieldset`

```
<fieldset id="type_selection" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <input type="radio" id="radio_option1" name="radio" checked="checked" />
    <label for="radio_option1">Option 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio_option2" name="radio" />
    <label for="radio_option2">Option 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio_option3" name="radio" />
    <label for="radio_option3">Option 3</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio_option4" name="radio" />
    <label for="radio_option4">Option 4</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: The problem I cannot select them in the first place. I want to navigate to the button with the arrowkeys and press enter to select it.

Comment: @PoweRoy: Use fieldset, rather than using div for control group

Comment: doesn't help. Keyboard navigation cannot reach the buttons.